# Why are elements not displayed in the same order as the HTML source?

Tags: html, css

In the main page I have two columns, one is for the menu (on the left) and one is for the data in the tab.

On the left column, I would like to have a "welcome" message, a profile picture and some of text menu. I want the items in the left column to be vertically align.

It should like this

Welcome message
Image
Text menu 1
Text menu 2
......

But as you can in my html and css code,

The text menu (Recommendation Request) is displayed above the  tag even though in the html it is declared under . How can I make my text menu displayed right under the  tag ?

```css
.main{
 background: #8CA3C6;
   border: 1px solid #42464b;
   border-radius: 6px;
   height: 700px;
  margin: 5em auto 0;
   width: 980px;
   padding: 20px;
}

.title {
 background: #003380;

}

.title h1 {
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 20px;
 padding: 5px;
 color: #FFF;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.row {
 display: inline;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;

}

.col {
 float: left;
 width: 20%;
 border: 10px;
 border-color: #000;
 border-width: 1px;
}

.col h1 {
 font-size: 20px;
}

.col ul {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.col li {
 list-style: none;
}


.col1{
 float: left;
 width: 70%;
 border: 10px;
 border-color: #000;
 border-width: 1px;
}

.col2 {
 font-size: 1em;
 text-align: center;
 color:#fff;
 padding:1em 0;
 float: left;
 margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: right;
}

.image {
 border-width: 2px;
 border-style: dotted;
 margin: 1px;
 padding: 0;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 position: absolute;
}

.row2{
 float: none;
 display: block;
}

.menu {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 position: relative;
 height: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 float: none;
 display: block;
}

.tabs {
  width: 100%;
  float: none;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px 0 0 0px;
  text-align: left;
}
.tabs li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
.tabs input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
}
.tabs label {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #4D70A6;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.tabs label:hover {
  background: #19478D;
}
.tabs .tab-content {
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 25px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  left: 0;
  background: #003380;
}
.tabs [id^="tab"]:checked + label {
  top: 0;
  padding-top: 17px;
  background: #003380;
}
.tabs [id^="tab"]:checked ~ [id^="tab-content"] {
  display: block;
}

p.link {
  clear: both;
  margin: 380px 0 0 15px;
}
p.link a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  background-color: #612e76;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
p.link a:hover {
  background-color: #522764;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
 <div class="title"><h1>HOME</h1></div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col">
   <h1>Welcome</h1>
   <div>
    <img width="100" height="100" class="image" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/tristan-edwards/sevenesque/1024/Preview-icon.png">
   </div>
   <div class="row"> 
    <ul>
     <li>
      Recommendation Request
     </li>
    </ul>

   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col1">

   <ul class="tabs">
       <li>
           <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab1" checked />
           <label for="tab1">General Preference</label>
           <div id="tab-content1" class="tab-content">
             <p>
              test 1
              <br/>
              a
                <br/>
              a  <br/>
              a  <br/>
              a
             </p>
           </div>
       </li>
       <li>
           <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2" />
           <label for="tab2">Current Preference</label>
           <div id="tab-content2" class="tab-content">
             <p>
             test 2
             </p>
           </div>
       </li>
        <li>
           <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab3" />
           <label for="tab3">Current Recommendation</label>
           <div id="tab-content3" class="tab-content">
             <p>
             test 2
             </p>
           </div>
       </li>
         <li>
           <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab4" />
           <label for="tab4">Previous Requests</label>
           <div id="tab-content4" class="tab-content">
             <p>
             test 2
             </p>
           </div>
       </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the text "Recommendation Request" is right below the "Welcome" is because the image is positioned absolutely (`position: absolute`), which removes the image from the [normal flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#normal-flow) of the document. If you remove that declaration from the `image` class, the elements will line up as you expect based on the HTML.

If you actually need to position the image element, I would recommend you add `position: relative` to the parent container (`.col`), then absolutely position the child elements however you wish.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `position:absolute;` from .image class the "Recommendation Request" text will be positioned under the image.

```
.image {
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: dotted;
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/afLgo4a0/

Comment: lol, i'm too slow to answer. I'm glad you find your own solution :)

Answer (score -1):

Solved!

I only need to add

```
.image img{
vertical-align: middle;
```

}

to my CSS code

Comment: Not sure how this solves your problem. What your code (`.image img { vertical-align: middle; }`) says is this: *Assign `vertical-align: middle` to `img` elements that are descendants of the `.image` class.* Nothing in your code matches that selector combination.

Comment: my <img> tag's class is image

Comment: Right. So the proper selector would be `img.image {vertical-align: middle;}`. That targets an `img` with a class of `image`.